# How to divide text into columns, if I get text dynamically for database using Javascript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think a script makes a certain number of characters in each container can work. Do you know any script like that?
It is a responsive design I can use several css files but I need only one html file:

the problem is in text which I'll get dynamically so I have no idea how many characters I'll get. In desktop size the paragraphs are arranged one above the others. In Ipad size the paragraphs are arranged into two columns, some on right side and some on the left.

Comment: Please do a little research before posting a question: http://www.google.be/search?q=jquery+columns

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code problems that we can assist you with?

Comment: Can't...understand...English. /head explodes

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS3's `columns` to achieve that task with CSS alone, though it is not supported in IE8 and below;

```
div {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 560px;
}
```

As a fallback for IE you can use conditional comments and something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or Columnizer as suggested by other posters.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/VB4rT/) that gracefully degrades in IE.

Comment: I am a total CSS3 freak, but CSS3 Layout isn't good in any Cross-browser-ish way...  ...sadly

Comment: I hear ya, but it's all about progressive enhancement with a tint of graceful degradation now A' days :P

Answer (score 2):

There are som jquery plugins. For example: [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

you think something like this?

```
var yourText = $('selector');
$(yourText).each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length >= 200) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 200)0);
    }
});
```

It wiil get the first 200 letters.. for the next 200 you need to switch the variables 0,200  to 200, 400 unfortunately it will split a word and does not recognize that some letters are wider than others...