# How to set text position in TextView via HTML?

Tags: android, html, textview

I have a TextView in my application and a user can set any text in this TextView using HTML from the application settings. The user must be able to set the position of the parts of the text in this TextView using HTML tags. But TextView doesn't support 'table' tag or CSS. And I don't know how else to set the position. Is there some tag to set the position? Or maybe it is possible with HTML.TagHandler? If it is possible - how?

Two examples:

1. I want to set align="center" for one line in this TextView with HTML.
2. I want to separate text to two or three columns.

How can I do that?

Comment: realy poor explanation. please rectify your question so people can make any sence out of this .

Comment: Sorry. I changed my question and I hope my explanation is better now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is a WYSIWYG editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com). These would allow you to align text or use tables to separate text into multiple columns.

Comment: No-no. I didn't need WYSIWYG. Only static text with HTML and only in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

to set align, line must have its id or class, without it maybe you can use jquery to find needed line ant align text in it.

Maybe text is splited into paragraphs, than you can find needed paragraph with jquery.

To split text to columns is not so easy, try this: [How to divide text into columns, if I get text dynamically for database using Javascript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605637/how-to-divide-text-into-columns-if-i-get-text-dynamically-for-database-using-ja)

Comment: That is simple text aligned left in multiline TextView. I can make screenshot, but I didn't sure that help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<div align="center">Your line here</div>`.

[Check out this article to see all the supported HTML tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)